# If few columns are the same and then put the row values together in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following are the details

**Here is the data frame**

> 

```
Name| Filename| delimetier| good delimeter| bad delimeter
A     123       48         a                A
A     123       48                          A
B     123       48         b                C
C     123       49         c                B
A     123       48         d                D
A     123       48         c                E
B     123       48         d                F
```

**What I want is**

> 

```
Name| Filename| delimetier| good delimeter| bad delimeter
A     123       48         a, c, d          A, D, E
B     123       48         b, d             C, F
C     123       49         c                B
```

**Even there have null value and duplicates, ignore them. And I have tried use groupby() to solve it, but failed.**

Comment: Can you explain your grouping logic in more detail?

Comment: group the first 3 columns and then join the 4th 5th columns together

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` is the right approach. You only need to define a custom aggregate function:

```py
str_concat = lambda s: ", ".join(s.drop_duplicates().dropna().sort_values())
df.groupby(["Name", "Filename", "delimetier"]).agg(str_concat)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and could you please let me know how to custom an aggregate function?

Comment: The custom aggregate function can be a regular function or a lambda that a Series at input. When you groupby, you are essentially dividing a dataframe into subframes. Call `agg` will apply the custom aggregator on each column of that subframe.